# find a bounded projection on Cesaro function space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Fix $1<p<\infty$.  Let us define the increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by the rules $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+n^{-p}$ (so that $a_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^nj^{-p}$).  Set
$$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j^p}.$$
We define the Cesaro function space $Ces_p[0,r]$ as the Banach space of all measurable functions $f:[0,r]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\|f\|_{Ces_p[0,r]}=\left[\int\limits_0^r\left(\frac{1}{x}\int\limits_0^x|f(t)|\;dt\right)^p\;dx\right]^{1/p}<\infty$$
We also define the Cesaro sequence space $ces_p$ as the Banach space of all scalar sequences $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ satisfying
$$\|(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\|_{ces_p}=\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k|c_n|\right)^p\right]^{1/p}<\infty$$

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\chi_n$ denote the indicator/characteristic function
$$\chi_n(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1,&\text{ if }t\in[a_n,a_{n+1})\\0,&\text{ otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$
Now set
$$f_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}-a_n}\cdot\chi_n,\;\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Using elementary techniques, I have been able to prove the following.

**Theorem 1.** There is $\delta\in(0,1)$ with
$$\delta\|(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\|_{ces_p}
\leq\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nf_n\|_{Ces_p[0,r]}
\leq\|(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\|_{ces_p}\;\;\;\text{ for all }(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in c_{00}$$
(where $c_{00}$ denotes the space of scalar sequences with finitely many nonzero entries).

Consequently, the Cesaro function space $Ces_p[0,r]$ contains an isomorphic copy of the Cesaro sequence space $ces_p$.

**Question 1.** Is the above isomorphic copy of $ces_p$ complemented in $Ces_p[0,r]$?

My idea is to define a projection $P$ by the rule
$$(Pg)(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p\int\limits_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}g(s)\;ds\cdot\chi_n(t).$$
If $P$ is bounded on $Ces_p[0,r]$, then it is a projection onto $[f_n]_{n=1}^\infty$.

**Question 2.** Is the above operator $P$ bounded on $Ces_p[0,r]$?

Thanks guys!